# Proxying MMS Stream on a LAN

Tags: proxy, streaming, lan

A variety of users on our LAN would like to listen to an MMS stream, and in the interest of conserving bandwidth (and because our WAN connection is not fast at all) I was wondering if it was possible to set up a service which proxies the stream from the WAN and provides it to LAN computers, thus only downloading the stream once and then distributing it to clients. Any ideas?

I have a Linux box serving as our LAN-WAN router, so it'd be ideal if something could sit on it and proxy the stream, but I also have Linux and Windows workstations. A free solution would be preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that VLC is able to take an input stream and rebroadcast it over a variety of protocols (or even write it to a file).

1. Go to Media -> Streaming, insert the URL of the stream, and then click "Stream".
2. Add new destinations for the media
3. Click "Stream" to begin streaming